# Remove :hover color from text without setting the color

Tags: css, hover

I would like to remove the :hover color from the text. However, knowing what the non-hover color is not possible in this case. Is there a way to set the color to inherit from its non :hover <s>parent</s> self? I can see and modify the element:hover CSS but not the element CSS.

Clarification: I want the link to inherit the color from its non-hovered state so that hovering does not have an effect on the element's color.  I encapsulated a div in a link so that the entire div would be a link, but I don't want that to change the text's color inside the div. I am changing the background color instead.

Comment: Sorry, I think I can't understand the question. What I can't understand is if you don't want to change the color at hovering, you can leave the `:hover` css without adding the `color:` property. Why can't you do it in this case?

Comment: This is what I have: http://jsfiddle.net/WAYZx/ I do not want the color of the text to change when the user hovers over the text, however, I do not have access to the original color to set it back to in the CSS nor can I remove the a:hover attribute.

Comment: Ah, you were referring to taking the non-hover color of the same element, not its parent. I was confused. I've removed my answer since it no longer applies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot. There is no undo in CSS. That is, if some style sheet assigns a property to an element, or to a state of an element, there is no way to tell a browser behave as if that rule were not there. You can override its effect, but this means setting the property to a value (which could be `inherit`, but that won’t help here, since inheritance is from a parent).