# How to reset (undo) a:hover property

Tags: css, hover, css-selectors, anchor, background-image

In the HTML below, there are three `<style>` blocks. The second block is the unwanted one, which makes the image disappears when mouse hover. The first two blocks are un-editable. We have to use the third block to cancel out the effect of the second block. Given an example of the third block below, **but that does NOT work.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


<style>
a {
  display: inline-block; width: 280px; height: 32px;
  background-image: url('http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3logotest2.png');
}
</style>



<style>
/* some bad guy did this */
a:hover {
  background-image: none;
}
</style>



<style>
/* to revert what the bad guy did */
/* but this is NOT work! */
a:hover {
  background-image: inherit !important;
}
</style>



</head>

<body>
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com/"></a>
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks very much for you inputs.

---

Note that, (sorry, i didn't make it clear enough), this is just an example. In the real case, there are many `<a>` with the first block setting them to different images. Just Only One second block ruins them all. As there are many (unlimited in fact, as it is a dynamic page) `<a>`, it is impossible to handle them one by one. I wish to have only one third block, that can revert the effect of the evil second block. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The trick is priority of the Style attributes.. You should already be knowing that there are three types of CSS styling. (1) Inline (2) In header section (3) external CSS file.. The priority is as I have listed. So if you add something in In Header section, it will overwrite the definition in CSS file. Inline style will overwrite everything else.

Answer (score 0):

write:

```
<style>
    a:hover {
        background-image: url('http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3logotest2.png'); 
    } 
</style>
```

Comment: Oh yes, thanks for your help! But there are many different <a>. It is impossible to list them all. However, the second block can ruin all the <a> by just appears once

Answer (score 0):

It's a typo: you have one extra `}` in your style, remove this.

```
a {
  display: inline-block; width: 280px; height: 32px;
  background-image: url('http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3logotest2.png'); }
}
```

it should like this:

```
a {
  display: inline-block; width: 280px; height: 32px;
  background-image: url('http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3logotest2.png');
}
```

And also provide background-image url because inherit just inherits from it's parent not previously defined.

Comment: Oh yes! Thanks. But the problem is still not fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand you now.

Each anchor has a different background image.

Some guy went and set that url to none on hover. (and you obviously have no access to the markup)

Now you want to return that url on hover.

Well, sorry, but as far as I know you can't do this in CSS.

CSS has no 'undo' in this context.

See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13429312/703717).

---

If this is the only block of anchor elements you could use nth-child to target the second one.

```
a:nth-child(2):hover {  
      background-image: url('http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3logotest2.png'); } 
    }
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/j4qQA/1/)**

---

The anchor element in question must have a value for href so you could target that via the attribute selector

```
a[href="http://your-website"]:hover {  
  background-image: url('http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3logotest2.png'); } 
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/j4qQA/)**

If you hover over the second element in the above fiddle, you'll see that hovering over it doesn't make it disappear.

Comment: Thanks and very nice illustration. But targetting url doesnt work in my case. Please see the edit section in the question. Thanks!

Comment: does that anchor have a class or id attribute? Alternatively, does it's parent element have a class or id?

Comment: Yes, anchors have classes. But each anchors are of different classes. So in first block they are set to different images. Also, their parent element has a class as well. I wish to reset all (umlimited) anchors, not just only the second one.

Comment: @midnite - I updated my answer. I don't think you can do this.

Comment: Oh yea Thanks for understanding me. I am considering remove it by JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<style>
a {
  display: inline-block; width: 280px; height: 32px;
  background-image: url('http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3logotest2.png');
}
</style>



<style>
/* some bad guy did this */
a:hover {
  background-image: none;
}
</style>



<style>
/* to revert what the bad guy did */
/* but this is NOT work! */
.toggle-a:hover {
  background-image: inherit !important;
}
.toggle-a a{
  float: left !important;
}
.bg-hover{
  background-image: inherit !important;
}
</style>



</head>

<body>
<div class="toggle-a">
 <a class="overwrite" href="http://www.w3schools.com/"></a>
<div>
<script>
$(function(){
  $('.overwrite').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).addClass('bg-hover');
  }).mouseout(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('bg-hover'); 
   });
});
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Excuse me! Do you know where the second block is?

Comment: Sorry, your code doesnt work in my place. And i have located the place of the second block... any helps? Thanks!

Comment: Did you embed jquery in your page? I have just update my answer, please try it again. Hope can help you

Comment: i am not so familiar with jquery. Why you have to add it before removing it? Why not just remove it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42164/discussion-between-hicurin-and-midnite)

Comment: jquery is a javascript library, so it's more powerful and help you to use javascript easier. I force add class because if you add css style after the other one, browser will use it instead so hope resolve your problem.